# Local variables get updated after eventBus.emit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I couldn't think of a better title, I'll try to explain it briefly & provide my example.

I'm using Vuetify as a framework and added a few `v-text-field` to the `template`. This didn't happen before, only happening in this specific component.

So, I'm getting the values of the `v-model` and sending them using `eventBus.emit`. Now, after the `emit`, I'm resetting the values to null. But, doing this, will update the sent data via `emit` which is pretty weird. I'm not re-sending them again after nullifying them.

I'm checking using `console.log(payload)` and the data is correct! After the `v-dialog` is `false`, this sent data gets automatically nullified. This shouldn't happen at all.

Template:

```
<template>
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" scrollable width="500">
    <v-card>
        <v-card-title primary-title class="title" primary-title>
            Add</v-card-title>
        <v-divider class="menu_divider_no_margin"></v-divider>
        <v-card-text>
            <v-container fill-height grid-list-lg>
                <v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" lazy-validation>
                    <v-layout wrap row fill-height>

                        <v-flex xs6>
                            <v-text-field v-model="season_payload.season.title" label="Title"></v-text-field>
                        </v-flex>

                        <v-flex xs6>
                            <v-text-field v-model="season_payload.season.number" label="Number" type="number" :rules="rules.generic" required></v-text-field>
                        </v-flex>


                    </v-layout>
                </v-form>
            </v-container>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-divider class="menu_divider_no_margin"></v-divider>

        <v-card-actions class="v-card-actions-custom-rtl">
            <v-btn flat @click.prevent="dialog = false">Close</v-btn>
            <v-btn flat @click.prevent="addItem">Add</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>

    </v-card>
</v-dialog>
</template>
```

Script:

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            constants: constants,
            valid: false,
            dialog: false,
            item_payload: {
                create: true
            },
            rules: {
                generic: [v => !!v || 'Required!']
            },
            season_payload: {
                season: {
                    number: null,
                    title: null
                }
            }
        }
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        this.$eventBus.$off('test_compo')
    },
    watch: {
        dialog(newValue) {
            if (!newValue) {
                this.item_payload.create = true

                this.season_payload.season.number = null
                this.season_payload.season.title = null

                this.$refs.form.resetValidation()
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        let app = this
        app.$eventBus.$on('test_compo', (payload) => {

            app.dialog = true
        });
    },
    methods: {
        addItem() {
            let app = this
            let payload = {
                season: app.season_payload.season,
                create: app.item_payload.create
            }


            app.$eventBus.$emit("reference", payload)
            app.dialog = false
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a problem with mutating a reference type.

Let's start here:

```js
let payload = {
    season: app.season_payload.season,
    create: app.item_payload.create
}
```

`app` is just an alias for `this`, the current component.

`app.season_payload.season` is an object. The newly created `payload` object has a `season` property that is pointing at the same object. It isn't a copy, it's the same object.

Then we have this:

```js
this.season_payload.season.number = null
this.season_payload.season.title = null
```

This is updating the `number` and `title` properties of the object `this.season_payload.season`. This is the same object that we saw in the earlier bit of code. It's the same object, so changing it here will also impact anywhere else that is using it.

Anything that has hold of this same `season` object is going to get the nulling out. It is, after all, the same object.

To avoid this you'd need to create a new object somewhere along the line. There are several opportunities to do this. e.g. We could have created the payload like this:

```js
let payload = {
    season: {
        number: app.season_payload.season.number,
        title: app.season_payload.season.title
    },
    create: app.item_payload.create
}
```

or:

```js
let payload = {
    season: {...app.season_payload.season},
    create: app.item_payload.create
}
```

As `number` and `title` are both primitives there's no lasting link to `app.season_payload.season`.

Alternatively we could have written the nulling out differently:

```js
this.season_payload.season = {
    number: null,
    title: null
}
```

Comment: Words literally can't describe how much you helped me. There's no way to possibly "replicate" the object without defining it again all over?

Comment: @Jaeger If you wanted to make a shallow copy you could use `{...season}`, or use `Object.assign({}, season)`. A common trick for deeper copies is `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(season))` but that only works if all the properties can be expressed as JSON. Various libraries, such as lodash, have utilities for handling more complicated cases but ultimately a true deep copy is not possible in JavaScript. I'll update my answer with the shallow copy version.

Comment: Thank you again for your follow-up!